# how to give more space for header in qweb report odoo-13 ?when am adjusting in paper format,its not getting,can anyone help me?

Tags: header, odoo-13, qweb

[See,The first 3,4 body parts are below header,I gave padding top,then it will be alright for 1st page,then 2nd page will be like this :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbHtt.png)

Answer (score 0):

If paperformat is not working then, You can try break tag to create a space. It leaves a line for a single tag.